# having trouble installing django on centos 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, linux, centos

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0FA1.png)

**been trying to install django on my venv on centos 7. I'm new to using centos and linux in general so i'm having trouble finding out what's causing these errors shown on the screenshot. If it's not clear on the picture I've also pasted it here below. Also, I'm not sure if having two versions of python is maybe causing this. I installed 3.6.8 using the package manager because i did not have an idea that that was the latest version available there so i downloaded 3.10.5 and installed it too. However on the error message that is showing, it seems like 3.6.8 is being mention. I can't understand.**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 302, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 384, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 60, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 459, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 503, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 971, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 833, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 590, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 346, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 381, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 623, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 659, in unpack_http_url
    hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 882, in _download_http_url
    _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 603, in _download_url
    hashes.check_against_chunks(downloaded_chunks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/hashes.py", line 46, in check_against_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 571, in written_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/ui.py", line 139, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 560, in resp_read
    decode_content=False):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 436, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 401, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 307, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.')
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

Comment: Use `--default-timeout=100` parameter with the install command

Comment: pip3  --default-timeout=60 install django . try this

Comment: thank you for your answer but I wasn't able to try this since before checking in here, I tried selecting my python interpreter from my venv on visual studio then I tried sudo pip3 install django again and it actually worked.